# Can anyone identify the model/year of this Montgomery Ward bicycle?

Tags: identify-this-bike, used-bike

Can anyone identify this Montgomery Ward bicycle? The only markings I've found are pictured.

[image]
[image] .

Comment: There are no real distinguishing characteristics.  The reflectors suggest that it's not *real* old (newer than about 1975), but the same basic design has been used pretty much forever.  I would guess it was manufactured around 1990, but that's just a vague guess.

Answer (score 11):

This is a vintage Montgomery Ward, reverse pedal brake, now I could be wrong on this but the serial number C71967 that is on the rear stays is manufacture date, C=March, 71=1971, 967=where it was made, the actual serial number of this particular bicycle is located on the head tube, where the front fork is inserted, it should start with the letters HC, followed by 7 numbers, hope this is of some help, also the reflector on the front wheel might not be of this bike, I believe the ones that came with these bikes are the red and yellow mounted on a black oval body that slide and snap on to the spokes, yellow for the front wheel, red for the back wheel

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's interesting that the bike is so old -- I'd have guessed it was much newer from the typography on the chain guard.

Answer (score 7):

[image]I have had this same exact bike (same color, reflectors, grips, etc) since I got it used in 1972 or 3. Still using it. Love it. I put 800-1000 miles on it each year in Key West. Also have been from DC to Pittsburgh on it,on the C & O trail and Great Allegheny Passage. Rode it 12 miles today. I've never been on a chat board before, but I'll try to post a picture. Kinda clueless. By the way, I think I tossed the original seat about 5 years ago, and could kick myself.