# Interesting frame, not sure what I got

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

I just bought this nifty looking bike, but alas I don't know the manufacturer or model it is. There's a logo with a silver looking "Z" and a made in Taiwan sticker. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. There was also a sticker that said the bike was "Manufactured Exclusively for S.B.S. Inc., Seattle". Seattle Bike Supply closed about 5 years ago.

[image: overview]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The frame looks like https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/41626/can-anyone-identify-the-model-year-of-this-montgomery-ward-bicycle but it will be something different. Mabebe some generic production

Comment: Concur - its modern, because of the rear derailleur.  Is based on a 70s cruiser-style but with somewhat better parts and modern 26" wheels.

Comment: Department store bike from about 1990, I would guess.

Comment: Is that a "Z" on the stickers located on the fork, head tube and seat tube? Please add a photo of the logo and a better shot of the rear drop out.

Comment: I added pictures of the Z logo and rear drop out. It seems like this frame was modeled on the Schwinn Phantom Cruiser, and that this frame was manufactured for Seattle Bike Supply (closed in 2015) - see updated post body.

Comment: The other dropout, where the derailleur is mounted, is more interesting.

Comment: I've added a picture of the rear dropout, drive side. There's a Shimano SIS derailleur mounted for this 6 speed cassette.

Comment: David D. Thank you! Wow, nice sleuthing. I just finished taking the bike down to the frame. I'm giving her a thorough cleaning and replacing a few worn parts. I'm still trying to decide if I'm going to sell it. I picked it up for $35 and will probably put about $100 into it, new tires being most of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks a lot like this 1998 Zephyr Boardwalk 6
[image]

[BikePedia](https://www.bikepedia.com/Quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?Year=1998&Brand=Zephyr&Model=Boardwalk%206)

The [Boardwalk also came in a single speed](https://www.bikepedia.com/quickbike/BikeSpecs.aspx?Year=1998&Brand=Zephyr&Model=Boardwalk). Both bikes came in men's and ladies models.

Sorry about the bad picture, I looked for better ones.

The "Zephyr" brand was also used to on [BMX bicycles](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/zephyr/110263).
On the linked BMX bike the logo is similar and there is a "MANUFACTURED EXCLUSIVELY FOR S.B.S INC. SEATTLE WA" sticker.

If the BMX Museum is accurate the BMX bikes were made [between 1985 and 1999](https://bmxmuseum.com/bikes/zephyr/)

Interestingly there is also a "Torker Boardwalk 6" cruiser which looks a lot like the Zephyr. It turns out that:

> In 1984, the Torker Bicycle Company went bankrupt, and Seattle Bike Supply purchased the name.
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torker)

Comment: Almost every tube is curved. ;)